# Add user's input to autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Good Afternoon,

Junior developer question...

I'm using jquery autocomplete in this tagging plugin:

```
$('#hh').tagEditor({
  duplicateTagClass:'bounce',
  initialTags:['Insert','tags','here'],
  placeholder: 'Insert tags here',
  autocomplete: {
    delay: 0,
    minChars: 1,
    position: {collision:'flipfit'},
    source:  ['a','b','c']}
```

I need to know how to insert in the local array the user's input.
The user types 'a', autocomplete shows results but if the users types 'k' press enter i need that 'k' value to be saved as part of the autocomplete source.

Hope i explained myself clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JavaScript code you have is either incomplete or invalid. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check https://jsfiddle.net/alanshearer/hfgz5e6e/4/
You can use onChange callback for tageditor widget to work out your issue:

HTML:

```
<input id="tags-editor" />
```

Javascript:

```
var source = ['a','b','c'];

var tagseditor = $('#tags-editor').tagEditor({
    duplicateTagClass:'bounce',
  initialTags:['Insert','tags','here'],
  placeholder: 'Insert tags here',
  autocomplete: {
    delay: 0,
    minChars: 1,
    position: {collision:'flipfit'},
    source: source
  },
  onChange: function(field, editor, tags) {
  var value = tags.reverse()[0];
  if ($.inArray(value, source) =='-1')
      source.push(value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Mother of God this works! Are you one of the plugin creators? can you explain me the logic behind why it works. Thanks a lot!! when i grow up want to be a good developer like you jejeje.

Comment: haha... Unfortunately I'm not!!
you're welcome!!

Comment: Then, about the logic:
if you add an element, function onChange is called and it gives you back three parameters, In this case you need only the third one: tags, that represents the array of inserted elements - and obviously the last one inserted. You make a check if last element is contained in source array and if not add it to.